# How did the Suryanshi come to know about death of "Maha Guru" faster than Shaktimaan?

Tags: shaktimaan

Shaktimaan, Geeta and Ruakchins were trapped in cave of Tamaraj Kilvish. The Maha Guru came at the main time to rescue them. He sends them off using Satya Punj and faced Kilvish all by himself. In that battle, Kilvish killed him by deceit.

When Shaktimaan returned back to Himalya, he came to know about death of Maha Guru.
My Question: How did message of death reach the Suryaanshis of Himalya instantly and Shaktimaan failed to get that?

**Update:**
The episode I am talking about is this:

Comment: Been a long time since I saw shaktimaan, is it still playing on some channel? It was on DD-1 during my childhood times.

Comment: @WeareBorg Search the YouTube. All episodes are available.

Comment: Yes, But I didn't go and exclusively watched them, just didn't came to my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the previous Episode (Episode 72). Mahaguru already told Satya Punj that "If I have to get sacrificed for saving people, please choose Mahaguru, there are plenty of Yogis." After that only he was given Shakti Dandh (Light Saber).

The moment he died, his Shakti Dandh was also lost with him (kind of tracking device, you know) because it was given by Satya Punj, hence Suryaanshis got to know that Mahaguru is no more.

Although, it's not obvious and also it was not shown, how the word had reached them. But it was predictable that if all those people have to be saved then someone has to be bait.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer lies deep within the spirituality of India. The Suryamshis are great sages, and have great mastery over the art of meditation. As such, they could somehow sense the death of Mahaguru, like we can understand when a fire has burnt out completely. This is one possible answer.

Comment: Only canonical answer, please...